# Xvideo extension not active with the radeon driver

Tags: linux, xorg, drivers, radeon, xvideo

On my computer running Debian squeeze with the `radeon` driver, the XVideo extension doesn't work (the extension itself is there but the hardware is not supported). `xvinfo` shows

```
X-Video Extension version 2.2
screen #0
 no adaptors present
```

The adapter is a Gigabyte Radeon X1650, shown by `lspci` as

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV535 [Radeon X1650 Series] (rev 9e)
```

The kernel driver is loaded, as `lsmod | grep radeon` shows:

```
radeon                574044  1 
ttm                    40018  1 radeon
drm_kms_helper         20065  1 radeon
drm                   142391  3 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit            4225  1 radeon
i2c_core               15712  6 eeprom,radeon,drm_kms_helper,drm,i2c_algo_bit,i2c_i801
```

The required (?) ([non-free](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/firmware-linux-nonfree)) firmware also seems to be loaded. From my kernel logs:

```
Mar 14 18:59:33 darkstar kernel: [   11.883832] [drm] Loading R500 Microcode
Mar 14 18:59:33 darkstar kernel: [   11.883834] platform radeon_cp.0: firmware: requesting radeon/R520_cp.bin
```

XVideo worked under Debian lenny. After upgrading to squeeze (Linux kernel: `2.6.32-5-vserver-amd64`; `xserver-xorg-video-ati 6.13.1-2+squeeze1`) it doesn't. How do I get it back?

[(link to the X server logs)](http://pastebin.com/sPchSp3g)

Comment: Maybe see if removing the free driver (`xserver-xorg-video-ati`) and the drivers it depends on works.

Comment: Have a look at your kernel config (`/boot/config-2.6.32...`) to see if has [all of these](http://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Configuringthekernel).

Comment: @Tshepang: I am using the stock Debian kernel, so it has the required pieces (and as I show the `radeon` module is loaded). How is removing the driver supposed to help?

Comment: @Gilles: This is a guess, but maybe when it's present, it's used, instead of the proprietary one.

Comment: @Tshepang: Why do you even mention the proprietary driver? I have the free one installed, I want to use the free one, it worked before (and I never got the proprietary one to start without a hard freeze).

Comment: @Gilles: You mentioning it led me to think it's the one you wanted to use. Sorry.

Comment: Does xdpyinfo | grep -i video show the extension as loaded?

Comment: And does grep -i xvideo /var/log/Xorg.0.log return anything interesting?

Comment: I can't seem to remove the last comment, but I noticed the log and it seems to say the extension is loaded.

Comment: @XTL: The extension is loaded, otherwise `xvinfo` would print a different message (`xvinfo: No X-Video Extension on :0`).

Comment: You considered filing a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dealt with this recently; it was a real pain, and unfortunately I don't have notes on exactly what I did.

I saved these two links:

- https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25607
- http://bgoglin.livejournal.com/19346.html

Recent radeon chips don't have dedicated video overlay hardware, they use the texturing support in the 3D core to emulate a video overlay. This means that 3D acceleration needs to be working for the video overlay to work. In my glxinfo I have:

```
OpenGL vendor string: DRI R300 Project
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI R300 (RV515 7145) 20090101  TCL DRI2
```

If you used the fglrx driver in the past, make sure that any remnants of it are removed (remove any packages found by `dpkg -l '*fglrx*'` and check for kernel modules in `/lib/modules`.

I currently have `radeon` in `/etc/modules`, as suggested at one of the links above, but I'm not sure if it's strictly necessary. There's nothing interesting in my `xorg.conf`.

Good luck!

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problems mentioned in the two links you cite were solved by the time squeeze was released. I already have `radeon` in `/etc/modules`, it is loaded with `modeset=1`, I have `radeon kernel modesetting enabled` in my kernel logs and `Loading extension DRI2` (but no other occurrence of `DRI2`) in my X logs. However `glxinfo` shows `Mesa X11` as the renderer, not `Mesa DRI`; I have `libgl1-mesa-swx11` installed, not `libgl1-mesa-glx`.

Comment: There is also some info at http://www.x.org/wiki/radeonBuildHowTo. libgl1-mesa-swx11 is probably not right. Do you have anything in the log for "textured video" or plain "dri"?

Comment: After removing the `fglrx-glx` and `fglrx-driver` packages (which were supposedly not used, I saw no trace in any log) and **installing `libgl1-mesa-glx` in place of `libgl1-mesa-swx11`**, XVideo works. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if this will help, but I found this post:

- http://swinky-linuxblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/xvinfo-no-adaptors-present-and-curious.html

Where the author seems to have fixed the problem, and several of the commenters claim it fixed it for them as well.

Comment: “The following is using the fglrx ATI proprietary drivers and ONLY applies to these drivers.” So it's irrelevant for this question, I'm using the open source `radeon` driver (which worked under lenny).